# Баг с символом в php 7 или в Apache 2.4 или

Tags: php, apache2.4

До конца не получается понять, в чём конкретно баг, но возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным багом. Если в адресной строке ввести русские символы, а именно букву **"Х"** (после которой должны идти ещё какие - то символы) то возвращается ошибка.
[http://localhost/ветхий](http://localhost/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9)
**Not Found**
**The requested URL /Ð²ÐµÑ‚Ñ…Ð¸Ð¹ was not found on this server.**
Эта проблема только с одним символом и в случае если используется autoload, проверить можно используя какой-нибудь фреймворк.
Без буквы **"Х"** страница открывается нормально.

В более низкой версии php такой проблемы нет, но опять же проблема может быть не в PHP, а самом apache или ОС.

Comment: используйте `urlencode` либо транслитерацию, да ещё непонятно как происходит роутинг php или apache осуществляет rout и т.д. т.е. для полного вопроса я думаю вам надо привести методы обработки запросов и конфигурации скорее всего у вас в роуте опечатка `ветхий` где `х` латинская икс а не русская. Проверить можно разложив строку в hex и сравнить коды символов исходной строки и строки в введённой в браузере

Comment: Здесь дело не urlencode, и роутинг здесь то-же не причём т.к. данная ошибка появляется абсолютно в разных фреймворках.

Comment: Какой фреймворк используйте? скопируйте настройки роутинга  из пары таких при которых возникают ошибки.

Comment: Например YII у вас установлен php7 ? Мне нужен человек у которого установлен php7. Иначе сложно будет понять т.к. данная проблема в других версиях php не наблюдается.

Comment: да установлен, но у меня с роутингом нет проблем, Not Found apache2 отдаёт проверьте доходит ли запрос до index.php как минимум? У меня была проблема подобная из за неправельного htaccess apache не доходил до index и отдавал 404 будто файла нет

Comment: Какой у Вас есть рабочий url? (например /blog/post/test-article) Если id исправить на тот который не существует вернёт ошибку 404 которую обрабатывает сам фреймворк. Какой у вас ещё фреймворк? И ещё можно скрин phpinfo основной верхней страницы, что бы понять что именно стоит ещё.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40934/discussion-between-vayas-and-naumov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная проблема появляется из-за особенностей ОС windows только на ней сохраняется подобная проблема, под UNIX всё работает отлично.
Исправить текущую проблему получилось редактированием файла .htaccess изначально он выглядел следующим образом:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

`.*` это регулярное выражение, однако просто `.` это не "любой символ" в регулярном выражении, а байпас исходного урла.
Регулярка не `^.$`, а значит достаточно чтоб в урле был минимум один любой символ. А он там всегда есть - лидирующий слэш.
 Для любой другой длины урла **точка** тоже будет срабатывать. Так сделано для снижения расходов на механизм регулярных выражений.

Поэтому постоянно и рекомендуют если разбором урла занимается пхп-роутер, то рерайт делать не `^(.*)$ index.php`, а `. index.php`.
 Вся соль одинокой точки в том чтоб быстро совпасть с любым адресом. В целом это даже не регулярка. Поэтому .htaccess исправил на:

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```